# Distance between a given world coordinate(uniform) and the current pixel being rendered in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, distance

I'am trying to make alpha larger the farther the pixel is from the lightsource.

How can I calculate the distance between my lightsource(u_lightSourcePosition) and the pixel being rendered?

I tried doing this:

```
float distance_from_point_to_pixel = distance(gl_FragCoord,v_lightSourcePosition)
```

but it didn't work.

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;
varying vec2 v_lightSourcePosition;


uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
uniform vec2 u_lightSourcePosition;

void main() {
    vec4 position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = position;
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoord0 = a_texCoord0;
    v_lightSourcePosition = u_lightSourcePosition ;

}
```

Fragment shader

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord0;

varying vec2 v_lightSourcePosition;

uniform sampler2D u_sampler2D;


void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_sampler2D, v_texCoord0) * v_color;
    float lightRadius = 400.0;
    float distance_from_point_to_pixel = distance(gl_FragCoord,v_lightSourcePosition);
    color.a = distance_from_point_to_pixel / lightRadius;
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: `length(current - uniform_point)`? Please add your shaders, otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: Sorry, first time posting. I've added the shader and some more info.

Comment: Most probably your points are not in the same space. `gl_FragCoord` is NDC which might not be the best space to calculate distances. Most probably you'll have to split up you transformations and pass a varying containing the world-space position to the fragment shader. Btw.: Why do you copy the uniform in a varying instead of just accessing it in the fragment shader?

Comment: @BDL `gl_FragCoord` is window space, not NDC

Comment: This is the first time I'am using a shader so I don't know how. All I want is the world position of the pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You need the world space of the fragment. Pass it from the vertex shader to the pixel shader as another `vec3` and you'll probably want to pass in a `world/model` matrix to translate `a_position` from object space to world space.  `vec3 pworld = (model * vec4(a_position,1.0)).xyz;`

Comment: I'am new to glsl. What is a world/model matrix?

Comment: Simply put, world/model matrix is the matrix by which you set the position+orientation+size of a model/mesh in world space. You can compute the world/model matrix of a model/mesh by following formula - `worldMatrix = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * scalingMatrix`. Here `translationMatrix` is the matrix which represent the translation of the model/mesh in world space. `rotationMatrix` is the matrix which represent the rotation of the model/mesh in world space. `scalingMatrix` is the matrix which represent the scale of the model/mesh.

Comment: Correct, if you don't know what your model matrix is, than you can substitute the Identity matrix...  But you want to supply matrices to all vertex shaders so that you can bring them into the correct view space.

An Identity matrix is simply...    
  
    `1, 0, 0, 0`  
    `0, 1, 0, 0`  
    `0, 0, 1, 0`  
    `0, 0, 0, 1`